# Amazon EC2 Chmod-ed etc to 644

Tags: amazon-ec2, chmod

Hy guys,

I chmod-ed /etc/ to 644 while logged in as ec2-user and now i cannot access /etc

" -bash: cd: etc/: Permission denied "

How can i get my permission back? I cannot login as root through putty - it says to log in as ec2-user.

I am a rookie in linux and AWS.

Comment: can you `sudo su`  after loging in as ec2-user to become root?

Comment: sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: If you could change permissions while logged in as ec2-user to being with then you should be able to change permissions now.  You can probably also just restart instance from original image to fix this problem.

Comment: @MikeBrant  he'd need to be careful restarting from image if he has anything stored on the instance not backed  up.

Comment: Do you have any ideea if withing the EC2 web console can be enabled the root login? That way i may login as root directly and maybe i have access to /etc/sudoers... - i don't have acces now to EC2 web console but i can get it.

Answer (score 1):

To get a root access log-in as ec2-user, then type `sudo su -` to change the user to root. After that you can change directory permissions back.

Also you can just use `sudo chmod` under ec2-user.

Comment: as i said in prev comment:    
-bash-4.1$ sudo chmod
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied  
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting  
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: Check if you're allowed to edit `/etc/sudoers` to add something like `ec2-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: that is the problem... i cannot access /etc/ anymore... 
"-bash: cd: etc/: Permission denied"

Comment: And what about `vi /etc/sudoers`? Probably you still have permissions to read/write this file.

Comment: I don't have any kind of permissions to /etc and inside :( i already tried these things. Do you have any ideea if withing the EC2 web console can be enabled the root login? That way i may login as root directly and maybe i have access to sudoers... -  i don't have acces now to EC2 web console but i can get it.

Comment: Check this approach: http://serverfault.com/questions/234061/re-gaining-root-access-to-an-ec2-ebs-boot-image

Comment: Exactly something like that i am in process of doing... it seems the only way. Thanks for your time!